# FACEBOOK LOGIN error 301

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

Hi i have a problem about Facebook login.So , when i try to entry clicking the login button safari opens it in authentication but after i put my data It remains firm on white page in which there is only done button

and if i click done button i return to my app and the login button is again whit the state "Login in Whit Facebook"

and when i call this method appear error 301

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
     fromViewController: self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Process error %@" , result);
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Logged in");
        }
    }];
```

Comment: before calling the method check if you hve the accessToken available or not.

Comment: yes!i check accessToken in viewWillAppear.but doesn't work or better there aren't accessToken available